# Mover una posición arriba varios elementos con la misma clase en jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

¿Cómo mover todos los elementos que contengan una clase específica y colocarlos antes del elemento superior?

Partiendo de esto:

```
<div>aaaa</div>
<div>bbbb</div>
<div clas="este">1111</div>
<div>cccc</div>
<div>dddd</div>
<div class="este">1111</div>
```

Quiero mover los `div` con clase `este` antes del `div` superior:

```
<div>aaaa</div>
<div clas="este">1111</div>
<div>bbbb</div>
<div>cccc</div>
<div class="este">1111</div>
<div>dddd</div>
```

Lo he intentado mediante esta función:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.este').each(function(){
    $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev());
  });
});
```

Se supone que recorre todos los `div` con clase `este` y los mueve encima del `div` superior.

El código completo sería:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.este').each(function() {
    $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev());
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>aaaa</div>
<div>bbbb</div>
<div class="este">1111</div>
<div>cccc</div>
<div>dddd</div>
<div class="este">1111</div>
```

Pero sólo mueve el primer div, ignora el segundo o siguientes si los hubiese.
La función `each` para recorre asumo que es correcta porque si en vez del `insertBefore` uso un `addClass` sí que me añade la clase a todos los `div`.

Supongo que o uso la función incorrecta (`insertBefore` o `prev`) o hay algún error en el selector del predecesor.

Comment: ¿Has notado que uno de tus elementos el parámetro es `clas` en vez de `class`? Corrige esto y comprueba el resultado.

Comment: Es error del copia pega, en el código completo está corregido

Comment: Hola Eloy. No sé si estás situando aquí en StackOverflow un resumen de tu error y tu código no es este exactamente o si estás intentando ejecutarlo en un navegador no convencional. ¿Pero has probado a ejecutar el snippet último después de la edición de @CaptTeach? Este snippet, en Chrome, Safari y Firefox hace lo que deseas y mueve todos los `divs` con la clase `este` una posición arriba.